# R matrix of lists

Tags: r, list, matrix

```
a=matrix(list(),2,2)
a[1,2]=list(2) ##works

a=matrix(list(),2,2)
a[1,2]=list(2,3) ##doesn't work
```

> Error in a[1, 2] = list(2, 3) :    number of items to replace is not a
>   multiple of replacement length

That's the error message from the fourth line. If I try

```
x=list()
x=list(2,4)
```

it works, I don't see the difference as `a[1,2]` is a `NULL` list..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish

Comment: A single matrix element can only be length 1, I believe.

Comment: I have a dataset that I want to put into a 2 dimensional matrix. Some (many) elements of the matrix will have multiple entries from the dataset, some elements of the matrix will have no elements, that's why I thought a 2 dimensional matrix of lists would work.

Comment: I think i've found a way to do it, fiddling around with:

`a=matrix(list(),2,2)
a[1,2]=list(rbind(c(2,3,4),c(2,3,1)))
a[1,2] `

Achieves what I need

Answer (score 1):

When you replace with `list(2)`, look at the output:

```
a=matrix(list(),2,2)
a[1,2]=list(2)    sapply(a, class)
# [1] "NULL"    "NULL"    "numeric" "NULL"
```

That is, the `[1,2]` element is *not* a `list`.

`list(2,3)` can be coerced like that to a single element; as RichardScriven points out, the replacement must be length-1; the following works (a bit silly, I agree):

```
a = matrix(list( ), 2, 2)
a[1, 2] = list(list(2, 3))
a
#      [,1] [,2]  
# [1,] NULL List,2
# [2,] NULL NULL
```

(just for reference, I figured this out by playing with `dput`, like so:)

```
#What happens if we declare 'a' as a
#  matrix of appropriately-sized lists to start with?
a <- matrix(replicate(4, vector("list", 2), simplify = FALSE), 2, 2)
a
#      [,1]   [,2]  
# [1,] List,2 List,2
# [2,] List,2 List,2
#
# can we replace now?
a[1,2] <- list(2,3)
# (same error; what IS 'a[1,2]' for this matrix?)
dput(a[1, 2])
# list(list(NULL, NULL))
# BINGO! we must replace 'a[1,2]' with a length-one list.
```